# Is a negative resistor a superconductor that does not require being cooled down to get 0 resistance?

Tags: oscillator, resistance

Title explains it, is it possible to create a superconductor using negative resistor oscillator / amplifier? As superconductors are conductors with 0 resistance. Isn't an amplifier a superconductor?

Or is what I am asking for wrong? I just need to learn.

Comment: So what, you don't even do some basic research on the stuff you're asking about? I would expect that you have at least read the wikipedia page on [superconductors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductors) before asking your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, *theoretically*, make a circuit that **acts like it is a superconducting wire** (or very close, anyways). This would require *active electronics*, which would take power, and as such it wouldn't be superconducting from the perspective of efficiency.

You really seem like you need to do a lot more reading. For example, you seem to not understand the difference between an amplifier or a superconductor.

Basically, a superconductor is a conductor with zero resistance. Period. It does not amplify, or really change the energy you put into it in any way.

An *Amplifier*, on the other hand, is basically a power-controlled (e.g. current or voltage input) power-source (e.g. current or voltage output).

Critically here is that an amplifier **requires another power source, from which to derive the additional power it produces** (and efficiency losses as well, but let's not go there).

---

At this point, the question becomes "what do you mean by `get a superconductor`".

If you mean "can I create a circuit that *when measured in certain ways* **looks** like a superconductor", the answer is yes. However, this circuit will **require power to function**, and internally **does not superconduct**. It would simply be *compensating* for the non-superconducting losses introduced by the internal wiring, and would require the commensurate amount of *additional* power.

If you are actually asking "can I create a room-temperature circuit that will conduct energy without any losses or requirement for external power", the answer is no. <sub><sup>If you *can* demonstrate room-temperature superconductance, it comes with a complementary Nobel Prize!</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you, this is good written and easy to understand :) answer for this one. The reason why I was wondering if because I was watching superconducters and the way they can levitate, Meissner effect... but thanks for letting me know this :)

Comment: @FriedBitz - The critical thing is a superconductor and an amplifier are really, really different things. As in, not really similar even a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, you put it really well in the description, I was just wondering if the system of where you use a amplifier would be similar to a superconducter. Which I learnt it's not.

Answer (score 1):

> Title explains it,

not to me

> is it possible to create a superconducter using negative resistor oscillator/amplifier?

No. A superconductor is passive component that has 0 resistance. There are circuits that behave as a negative resistance, but they are active circuits that *require power*. Hence is makes no sense to use them as a sort of replacement for superconductors: superconductors are used when massive currents must flow *without losing energy (power)*.

> As superconducters are conducters with 0 ressistance.

that is true

> Isn't a Amplifier a superconducter?

no. by now you should understand why.

Comment: Okai, so a negative resistor oscillator is not 0 resistance, it is simply just another source being added to increase the voltage? I am really fresh on electronics, but I really wish to learn... and my school doesn't seem to teach me about the things I really want to learn about....

Comment: A negative resistance is of course not 0 resistance, in the same sense that -1 is not 0. It behaves sort-of like a source of current-and-voltage that can compensate a resistance. It is an active component (can be used to amplify a signal, or to make an oscillator).

Comment: but if you can get negative resistance you can adjust it to receive exacly 0 resistance, so it takes away all the resistance in the wire creating a system resistance of 0

Comment: That is correct. But because that negative resistance is an active device that requires power, you have not achieved much.

Comment: No see what you mean, I have learned quite a bit today, as I have been researching different topics like this :) Its fun :)